# Get all checked checkboxes values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

i have the following form:

```
<%= form_for([company,service], :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <%= health_care_insurances.each do |hc_insurance| %>
        <label><%= hc_insurance.name %></label>
        <input id="health_care_insurance_<%= user.id %>" name="<%= hc_insurance.id %>" value="<%= hc_insurance.id %>" type="checkbox"><br/>
    <% end %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

When it's submited, and for the sake of good performance, i would like to get an array with all "hc_insurance.ids" that are checked. I know i might use javascript to add them to a hidden_field and then pick them up from there, but im not sure that's a good way to go.

Is there any rails way to pick them up from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make all the name of the checkboxes the same with array box, like below (this would submit only the checked values to the backend)

```
<input id="health_care_insurance_<%= user.id %>" name="health_care_insurence_ids[]" value="<%= hc_insurance.id %>" type="checkbox"><br/>
```

To get the id of all the health_care_insurence in controller (assuming health_care_insurence is a single model).

```
HealthCareInsurence.pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Hi @Coderhs, thanks but wouldnt that give me all health_care_insurence_ids instead of just the checked ones?

Comment: @ntonnelier you can get all the check box ids using the same code in controller health_care_insurances.map { |h| i.id }. Incase health_care_insurence is a helper include its corresponding helper module in the controller.

Comment: Thanks @Coderhs but the thing is i intended to spare the iteration through all HealthCareInsurance objects. Maybe there's just no simple way arount it.

Comment: If you are in Rails 4.1 +, you can do ``HealthCareInsurence.pluck(:id)``. That fetches just the id, without neading to iterate over all objects.

Comment: @ntonnelier it seems i missed your first comment. My first code will give only the checked values. It won't submit all the values to the backend..